# Extract numbers from chemical formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, chemistry

Apologies if this has already been asked and answered but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

I have a list of chemical formulas including, in this order: C, H, N and O. And I would like to pull the number after each of these letters. The problem is that not all the formulas contain an N. All contain a C, H and O however. And the number can be either single, double or (in the case of H only) triple digit.

Thus the data looks like this:

- C<sub>20</sub>H<sub>37</sub>N<sub>1O5</sub>
- C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>3</sub>
- C<sub>20</sub>H<sub>19</sub>N<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>
- C<sub>23</sub>H<sub>40</sub>O<sub>3</sub>
- C<sub>9</sub>H<sub>13</sub>N<sub>1</sub>O<sub>3</sub>
- C<sub>14</sub>H<sub>26</sub>O<sub>4</sub>
- C<sub>58</sub>H<sub>100</sub>N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>9</sub>

I'd like each element number for the list in separate columns. So in the first example it would be:

```
20 37 1 5
```

I've been trying:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A2,FIND("H",A2)-1),FIND("C",A2)+1,LEN(A2)),"")
```

to separate out the C#. However, after this I get stuck as the H# is flanked by either an O or N.

Is there an excel formula or VBA that can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Use Regular Expressions

This is a good task for [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) (regex). Because VBA doesn't support regular expressions out of the box we need to reference a Windows library first.

1. Add reference to regex under *Tools* then *References*
   [image]
2. and selecting *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5*
   [image]
3. Add this function to a module

   ```
    Option Explicit 

    Public Function ChemRegex(ByVal ChemFormula As String, ByVal Element As String) As Long
        Dim strPattern As String
        strPattern = "([CNHO])([0-9]*)" 
                     'this pattern is limited to the elements C, N, H and O only.
        Dim regEx As New RegExp

        Dim Matches As MatchCollection, m As Match

        If strPattern <> "" Then
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ChemFormula)
            For Each m In Matches
                If m.SubMatches(0) = Element Then
                    ChemRegex = IIf(Not m.SubMatches(1) = vbNullString, m.SubMatches(1), 1) 
                                'this IIF ensures that in CH4O the C and O are count as 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next m
        End If
    End Function
   ```
4. Use the function like this in a cell formula

   E.g. in cell B2: `=ChemRegex($A2,B$1)` and copy it to the other cells
   [image]

---

#### Recognize also chemical formulas with multiple occurrences of elements like `CH₃OH` or `CH₂COOH`

Note that the code above cannot count something like `CH3OH` where elements occur more than once. Then only the first `H3` is count the last is omitted.

If you need also to recognize formulas in the format like `CH3OH` or `CH2COOH` (and summarize the occurrences of the elements) then you need to change the code to recognize these too …

```
If m.SubMatches(0) = Element Then
    ChemRegex = ChemRegex + IIf(Not m.SubMatches(1) = vbNullString, m.SubMatches(1), 1)
    'Exit For needs to be removed.
End If
```

[image]

#### Recognize also chemical formulas with 2 letter elements like `NaOH` or `CaCl₂`

In addition to the change above for *multiple occurrences of elements* use this pattern:

```
strPattern = "([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)"   'https://regex101.com/r/nNv8W6/2
```

[image]

1. Note that they need to be in the correct upper/lower letter case. `CaCl2` works but not `cacl2` or `CACL2`.
2. Note that this doesn't proof if these letter combinations are existing elements of the periodic table. So this will also recognize eg. `Xx2Zz5Q` as fictive elements `Xx = 2`, `Zz = 5` and `Q = 1`.

   To accept only combinations that exist in the periodic table use the following pattern:

   ```
    strPattern = "([A][cglmrstu]|[B][aehikr]?|[C][adeflmnorsu]?|[D][bsy]|[E][rsu]|[F][elmr]?|[G][ade]|[H][efgos]?|[I][nr]?|[K][r]?|[L][airuv]|[M][cdgnot]|[N][abdehiop]?|[O][gs]?|[P][abdmortu]?|[R][abefghnu]|[S][bcegimnr]?|[T][abcehilms]|[U]|[V]|[W]|[X][e]|[Y][b]?|[Z][nr])([0-9]*)"
    'https://regex101.com/r/Hlzta2/3
    'This pattern includes all 118 elements up to today. 
    'If new elements are found/generated by scientist they need to be added to the pattern.
   ```

---

#### Recognize also chemical formulas with prenthesis like `Ca(OH)₂`

Therefore another RegEx is needed to handle the parenthesis and multiply them.

```
Public Function ChemRegex(ByVal ChemFormula As String, ByVal Element As String) As Long
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
    End With
    
    'first pattern matches every element once
    regEx.Pattern = "([A][cglmrstu]|[B][aehikr]?|[C][adeflmnorsu]?|[D][bsy]|[E][rsu]|[F][elmr]?|[G][ade]|[H][efgos]?|[I][nr]?|[K][r]?|[L][airuv]|[M][cdgnot]|[N][abdehiop]?|[O][gs]?|[P][abdmortu]?|[R][abefghnu]|[S][bcegimnr]?|[T][abcehilms]|[U]|[V]|[W]|[X][e]|[Y][b]?|[Z][nr])([0-9]*)"
    
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ChemFormula)
    
    Dim m As Match
    For Each m In Matches
        If m.SubMatches(0) = Element Then
            ChemRegex = ChemRegex + IIf(Not m.SubMatches(1) = vbNullString, m.SubMatches(1), 1)
        End If
    Next m
    
    'second patternd finds parenthesis and multiplies elements within
    regEx.Pattern = "(\((.+?)\)([0-9]+)+)+?"
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(ChemFormula)
    For Each m In Matches
        ChemRegex = ChemRegex + ChemRegex(m.SubMatches(1), Element) * (m.SubMatches(2) - 1) '-1 because all elements were already counted once in the first pattern
    Next m
End Function
```

This will also recognize parenthesis. Note that it does not recognize nested parenthesis.

[image]

---

Also have a look at a similar question: [Determine total number of atoms in a chemical formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642843/determine-total-number-of-atoms-in-a-chemical-formula/69643037#69643037)

Comment: This pattern is far better then mine. How do submatches work exactly? Does it then consider, for example `C20` as `C` and `20`. And if so, why does it recognise these as two separate `SubMatches`?

Comment: @Tom The submatches are generated by the brackets `()` in  `([CNHO]{1})([0-9]*)` if you remove them like `[CNHO]{1}[0-9]*` it would only match eg. `C20` without submatches.

Comment: Makes sense - Didn't know you could do this. I love `RegExp` more and more. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Tom There is a nice tool to play with regex: https://regex101.com/r/nNv8W6/1 They also have a good explanation what a specific pattern you entered stands for.

Comment: I use that one when testing patterns along with [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) just didn't realise you could do that as well

Comment: This does not properly count elements in a group, such as Ca(OH)2.  The regex doesn't know that (OH) is to be counted twice.

Comment: @TechnicalBard I never said it does ^^ Therefore the code needs to be enhanced. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work just fine:

[image]

Formula in `B2` is below. Drag across and down

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(--(MID($A2,SEARCH(B$1,$A2)+1,3)),IFERROR(--(MID($A2,SEARCH(B$1,$A2)+1,2)),--MID($A2,SEARCH(B$1,$A2)+1,1))),0)
```

Or a shorter array formula, which must be entered with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID($A2,SEARCH(B$1,$A2)+1,ROW($A$1:$A$3)),0))
```

---

If you wanted to keep the VBA super simple, something like this works as well:

```
Public Function ElementCount(str As String, element As String) As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String

    For i = 1 To 3
        s = Mid(str, InStr(str, element) + 1, i)
        On Error Resume Next
        ElementCount = CLng(s)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Function
```

Use it like so:

```
=ElementCount(A1,"C")
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this in VBA, using regular expressions. You can probably do it like Vityata suggests by looping through the string too, but I suspect that this is slightly faster and easier to read.

```
Option Explicit

Function find_associated_number(chemical_formula As Range, element As String) As Variant
  Dim regex As Object: Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  Dim pattern As String
  Dim matches As Object

  If Len(element) > 1 Or chemical_formula.CountLarge <> 1 Then
    find_associated_number = CVErr(xlErrName)
  Else
    pattern = element + "(\d+)\D"
    With regex
      .pattern = pattern
      .ignorecase = True
      If .test(chemical_formula) Then
        Set matches = .Execute(chemical_formula)
        find_associated_number = matches(0).submatches(0)
      Else
        find_associated_number = CVErr(xlErrNA)
      End If
    End With
  End If
End Function
```

Then you use the formula in your sheet like normal:

[image]

Column C contains the number of carbon atoms, column D the number of nitrogen atoms. Just expand on this by copying the formula and changing the element it searches for.

Answer (score 1):

With VBA this is an easy task - you have to loop through the chars and check the values for being numeric.
With Excel, the solution includes some redundancy. But it is doable. E.g.,

**C20H37NO5** will return **20375** if you apply the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,1,1)),MID(A1,1,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,2,1)),MID(A1,2,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,3,1)),MID(A1,3,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,4,1)),MID(A1,4,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,5,1)),MID(A1,5,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,6,1)),MID(A1,6,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,7,1)),MID(A1,7,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,8,1)),MID(A1,8,1),"")&
IF(ISNUMBER(1*MID(A1,9,1)),MID(A1,9,1),"")
```

Currently, it checks the first 9 characters for being numeric. If you want to include more than 9, then simply add a few lines to the formula.

There is a small trick in the formula - the `1*`. It converts a text character to a numeric, if it is possible. Thus, a `5` as a text, multiplied by `1` becomes a numeric character.

Answer (score 1):

Use split and like method.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim s As String
    Dim vSplit As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer

    vDB = Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To Len(s)
            If Mid(s, j, 1) Like "[A-Z]" Then
                s = Replace(s, Mid(s, j, 1), " ")
            End If
        Next j
        vSplit = Split(s, " ")
        For j = 1 To UBound(vSplit)

            vR(i, j) = vSplit(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("b2").Resize(n, 4) = vR
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a vba solution to extract all numbers my preferred solution is to use Regular Expressions. The following code will extract all numbers from a string

```
Sub GetMolecularFormulaNumbers()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RegExp As Object
    Dim match, matches
    Dim j As Long

    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegExp
        .Pattern = "\d+"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True

        For Each c In rng
            j = 0
            Set matches = .Execute(c)
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                For Each match In matches
                    j = j + 1
                    c.Offset(0, j) = CInt(match)
                Next match
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```